# Examples of not monotonic sequences which have no limit points?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What examples are there of not monotonic sequences which have no limit points ?

Comment: 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....

Comment: $+1,$ $-1,$ $+2,$ $-2,$ $+3,$ $-3,$ $\ldots$ is not monotonic and also does not have any convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $u_n=(-1)^n n$. (I assume you mean "no limit points in $\mathbb{R}$.")

Comment: To generalize this particular idea: take your two favorite increasing and decreasing sequences (diverging respectively to $\infty$ and $-\infty$), and interlace them.

Comment: could you please give me an example of this?

Comment: @iheartmaths Take $a_{2n} = \sqrt{n}$ and $a_{2n+1} = -\ln n$, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, an example is $(-1)^nn$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you choose an infinite set $X$ such that $\exists C > 0$ for which $|x - y| \geq C$ for all $x, y \in X, x \neq y$, then there exists a strictly increasing or strictly decreasing injective sequence $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to X$.

To see this, recall we chose the set infinite and such that it can have no limit points (the $C$ assures that a $C/2$-ball of any point in $X$ intersects only that point). Bolzano-Weierstraß says every bounded infinite set has a limit point, so $X$ must be unbounded. Assume WLOG it is unbounded above, i.e. $(\forall N \in \mathbb{N} ) (\exists x \in X)(x > N)$. Fix $\phi(1) = x_{1} \in X$, and let $\phi(n + 1) \in X \cap ( \phi(n) + 1, \infty)$. This definition does use choice, but it will give you a strictly increasing sequence $\phi$.

Now let $\psi (n) = \begin{cases}
\phi(1) & n = 1
\phi(n + 1) & 2 \leq n \equiv 0 \mod{2}
\phi(n - 1) & 2 \leq n \equiv 1 \mod{2} 
\end{cases},$ or $\psi = ( \phi(1), \phi(3), \phi(2), \phi(5), \phi(4), \phi(7), \phi(6), \ldots)$. Thus $\psi(1) < \psi(2) > \psi(3) < \psi(4) > \psi(5) < \cdots$ is not monotonic. But since it's injective, by the discreetness of $X$ you have that $\psi$ has no limit point.

EDIT: That's assuming you didn't want to look at limit points in incomplete spaces like $\mathhbb{Q}$.